# MySql error regarding update

Tags: mysql

What should i do for this error? This is my query:

```
UPDATE person  
SET 
  Name = '$Name', 
  Address = '$Address', 
  Email = '$Email', 
  Telephone = '$Telephone',  
WHERE Id = '$Id';
```

but when executing, it gives this kind of error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'WHERE Id = '$Id' at line 2`

Comment: Remove the comma before `WHERE`

Answer (score 3):

The issue is here

```
,  WHERE Id
```

their is an extra comma following `WHERE` in query, remove it. So the query is like:

```
"UPDATE person  SET Name = '$Name' , Address = '$Address' , Email = '$Email' , Telephone = '$Telephone'  WHERE Id = '$Id' ;"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mayank pandeyz

Comment: Enjoy the weekend :)